# Simplify T-SQL request

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-insert

So I have this code in the insert trigger. Basically, when i try to insert to atbl_sales_orderlines it checks if there is sufficient quantity in atbl_sales_products to insert new order. I was wondering if this could be done in a more efficient way (maybe using less SELECTS). Code below:

```
    BEGIN
        IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (
            SELECT x.ProductId, totalOrdersQty, ISNULL(asp.Quantity, 0) PossibleQty FROM (
                SELECT i.ProductId, sum(aso.Amount) totalOrdersQty 
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ProductId FROM inserted) i
                JOIN atbl_Sales_OrdersLines aso ON aso.ProductId = i.ProductId
                GROUP BY i.ProductId) x
            LEFT JOIN atbl_Sales_ProductS asp ON asp.ProductId = x.ProductId
            ) x
            WHERE PossibleQty < totalOrdersQty)) 
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Quantity is not sufficient' ,18,1)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
    END
```

P.S. I know such thing should be done before the trigger. I am doing this for learning purposes. Code works.

Comment: I feel this check should done before inserting into the trigger table which will avoid the unnecessary IO

Comment: I know, but im doing this for learning purposes. It needs to be performed in trigger.

Comment: Many SELECTS doesnt mean inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be simplified to remove one derived table though not sure about the performance difference

```
BEGIN 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   atbl_sales_products asp 
               WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM   (select distinct productid from inserted) i 
                                     JOIN atbl_sales_orderslines aso 
                                       ON aso.productid = i.productid 
                              WHERE  asp.productid = x.productid 
                              GROUP  BY i.productid 
                              HAVING Isnull(asp.quantity, 0) < Sum(aso.amount))) 
      BEGIN 
          RAISERROR ('Quantity is not sufficient',18,1) 

          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
      END 
END
```